# How to make a scrolling text box in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.textboxfor

I had one field something like Remarks such that is following,

```
  [DisplayName("Remarks" )]
  [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage =Constants.ErrorMessage.MinimumAndMaximumWouldBeSame)]
  public virtual string Remarks { get; set; }
```

And in my cshtml file

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <label for="" class="control-label">
       Remarks
   </label>
       @if (Model.Remarks != null)
       {
         @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Remarks, 2, 78, new { disabled = "disabled", style = "font-size: small;" })
       }
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AddedRemarks, 3, 78, null)        
</div>
```

In which the AddedRemarks field's data is appended to the Remarks field. If the data are so long then the Remarks field shows only few line and I can not see the full data by scrolling due to it is disabled.

So how to view the full data in a texbox field which is in disabled mode.   Please Can anyone help to find the solution.

Comment: try `readonly` not `disabled`

Comment: Why would you disable it (which means it won't post back so its a bit pointless making it a `<textarea>` If you don't want it to post, just put the contents in a div (and make it scrollable) or use a textarea and make it readonly

Comment: And what is the point of `[DisplayName("Remarks" )]` when you don't make use of it (in any case it should be `[Display(Name = "Remarks"]` and then in the view you have `<label for="" ..>` which is not even related to the associated control!

Answer (score 1):

Your View should looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Remarks, new {@class = "control-label"})
    @if (Model.Remarks != null)
    {
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Remarks, 2, 78, new { style = "font-size: small;" })
    }
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AddedRemarks, 3, 78, new { })        
</div>
```

You should also change Data Annotations for `Remarks` property, please use `[Display(Name ="Remarks")]` as @Stephen Muecke mentioned.

I sugest also to improve if condiotion to

```
 @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Remarks) != false)
 {
      //...
 }
```